# Cropping Images in Java

Tags: java, image, crop

I am trying to build a code for OMR recognition using Java. I am facing a problem when the objects in the scanned image do not have the same positions as the template Image I use.

To solve this I decided to place borders in the Image and when I cut out the Image using the borders, I can get proper values. Now for this I have been cutting out the Images manually, but I want to cut the Images using Java as well.

I know that I can get a rectangular selection from the `CropImageFilter` class. But how can I let the program know the point from where it needs to begin? Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but your question is very unclear to me.

Comment: Not your down-voter by the way.

Comment: If you want to find the position of the mark, maybe take a look at open source, links in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition).

Comment: Yes I know my question is a little unclear. I could not frame it properly. What I actually need is the pixel of the first non-white point of an image. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might edit your question and add that information

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Java 7

Then the simplest way i know of doing this is:

```
  private BufferedImage cropImage(BufferedImage source, Rectangle newDim) {
      return source.getSubimage(0, 0, newDim.width, newDim.height);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the [Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/CropImageFilter.html#CropImageFilter-int-int-int-int-) of `CropImageFilter`:

> `CropImageFilter(int x, int y, int w, int h)`
>   Constructs a CropImageFilter that extracts the absolute rectangular region of pixels from its source Image as specified by the x, y, w, and h parameters.

Comment: Yes I know about this. What I want to know is how to get the x and y values for an image.